# python-chess - AttributeError: module 'chess' has no attribute 'pgn'

Tags: python, python-chess

I'm trying to export a python-chess game to a pgn file. The [documentation](http://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pgn.html) recommends -

```
import chess
.
.
chessBoard = chess.Board()
.
.    
#Play the game and when over do below
game = chess.pgn.Game.from_board(chessBoard)
with open('output.pgn', 'a') as the_file:
    print(game, file=the_file, end="\n\n")
```

But the `chess.pgn.Game.from_board(chessBoard)` line throws the below error -

> AttributeError: module 'chess' has no attribute 'pgn'

`pgn` shows up in intellisense as well when I type `chess.` so the editor is also able to see that there is a `pgn` in `chess`. This is python 3.x running in VS2015 on windows 10.

What could be causing it?

Comment: I had the same sort of error:  `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'svg'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use the `pgn` module you'd also have to do `import chess.pgn`

Answer (score 4):

For those of you who didn't get it to work with the accepted answer, check if you have named your file `chess.py` (where you have written `import chess`). If that's the case change it to something else, like `pychess.py`.

The reason it doesn't work having your file named `chess.py` is, I believe, that it's then essantially importing itself, and of course there is no `chess.Board()` there.